# Grep and output to a file between two known nodes

Tags: terminal, grep, tail

I have the following information being logged:

```
<MessageForTransform>
    <node>
        <taster></taster>
    </node>
</MessageForTransform>
```

I am trying to figure out the regex to pull all of the information between and including the `<MessageForTransform>` tags.

Bonus points for using `tail -f` to watch and output to a file, I think the format is as follows:

`$ tail -f logFileToRead.txt >>logFileToWrite.txt | grep "regex"`

I was using the following regex

`\<MessageForTransform\>[^]\<\/MessageForTransform\>`

I'd like to give more information but this really as far as I can get without knowing the regex which I have had a look around for. The above works on regex checker if I post the raw XML into the page but not in the terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Usually... we don't use a regexp to parse an XML file !

But **if you are sure** that your xml files are using a standard way of being formatted, with separated lines starting and ending what you want to log, then you could awk this:

```
awk -v delimitertag="MessageForTransform" '
   BEGIN              { weprint=0 ; sd="<"delimitertag">"; ed="</"delimitertag">"}
   ( $0 ~ sd )        { weprint=1;}
   ( weprint == 1 )   { print $0 ;}
   ( $0 ~ ed )        { weprint=0;}
  '   your_file_here  #... or nothing if you want to parse stdin
```

I go for readability over terseness (I'm sure you'll get better ways than this one)

It's easy to modify to not print the starting/ending lines, too.

And to add a little bit of flexibility, for ex:   `sd="<"delimitertag"[^>]*>";` in case those tags can have optionnaly some additionnal values embedded

Comment: Hi, thanks for this I'll check it out. I'm using this to basically pull a load of XML data that is inside a huge file that has a lot of junk that isnt the XML I want.

Comment: So er, I throw this in a bash script or what? I'm incredibly new to terminal stuff...

Comment: You can run this directly at your terminal prompt (copy/paste it as a whole). If placed in a file, there are several ways to do it (source the file, or have it run awk directly but you'll need to change the option and arrange it a bit differently). And just replace `your_file_here` with the name of the original file, and add just after it the redirection to the new file (before the "#"). hence in my answer, replace `your_file_here` with `logFileToRead  > logFileToWrite`.